# BETWEEN Versus >= and <= in DB2 SQL Query - Performance

Tags: db2, query-optimization

I have the following querys:

```
SELECT ID, ADDRESS 
FROM EMPLOYEE A 
WHERE ID=12345 
AND CURRENT DATE BETWEEN A.EFF_DT AND A.EXP_DT 

SELECT ID, ADDRESS 
FROM EMPLOYEE A 
WHERE ID=12345 
AND CURRENT DATE >= A.EFF_DT AND CURRENT DATE <= A.EXP_DT
```

Out of these two queries which query yields better performance.

Here I am using operators >= and <= instead of BETWEEN.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please avoid the use of `BETWEEN` whenever possible, and it's actually usually best to do _exclusive_ upper bounds (`'<'`) for ranges, especially date/time/timestamp types (you don't really want to have to construct microseconds, do you?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both those should give you exactly the same execution profile, based on my knowledge of DB2/z (the LUW product may be different but I doubt it).

If you're really concerned, you should run an [EXPLAIN](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000952.htm) on the two queries to see if there are any differences.

Answer (score 5):

Between is simply a shorthand for >= and <= ,

if want find more help go to the link is here: [Is the 'BETWEEN' function very expensive in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582582/is-the-between-function-very-expensive-in-sql-server)

Comment: Except he's running this on DB2, so a discussion of SQL Server isn't necessarily applicable.  Although in this case it's probably implemented the same way.